# How to check if submit name is there or not in self.client.post?

Tags: django, unit-testing

Here I am writing test for function `delete_position` but I got little problem here.I am getting `AssertionError: 302 != 200` which is I think because I have not send `delete_single` name in `client.post` but it is defined in my views.

How can I check if `delete_single` is in request.POST in my `test_delete_position` ?

views.py

```
def delete_position(request, pk):
    position = get_object_or_404(Position, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'delete_single' in request.POST:
        position.delete()
        messages.success(request, '{} deleted.'.format(position.title))
        return redirect('organization:view_positions')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Sorry.Invalid request.')
```

tests.py

```
class PositionTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create admin user for authentication

        self.admin = get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(username='admin', password='password@123',email='admin@admin.com')

        self.client = Client()

        self.position = Position.objects.create(title='Sr.Python Developer')


        def test_delete_position(self):
           self.client.login(username='admin', password='password@123')
           response = self.client.post(reverse('organization:delete_position', kwargs={'pk': self.position.pk}))
           print(response)
           self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: A 302 is the expected result of a succesful DELETE.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I should do `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)` then ?

Comment: Yes, you should check for 302 if your delete request is successful. But your `delete_position` view isn't returning anything in the `else` case. This would probably raise a 500 error somewhere. And you want to [pass POST data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#overview-and-a-quick-example) to your `self.client.post()` method, in order to set `delete_single`.

Comment: You should probably also test that the position was actually deleted, e.g. by counting the number of objects in the database (`Position.objects.count()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here I am writing test for function delete_position but I got little problem here.I am getting AssertionError: 302 != 200 which is I think because I have not send delete_single name in client.post but it is defined in my views.

A 302 is *expected* behavior in case of a succesful POST. This is the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). In case the POST was successful, then a 200 means that if the user refreshes that page, he/she will make the same POST request again. In order to prevent that, usually it will return a redirect (HTTP status 302), and the browser will then make a GET request to fetch the object.

It is thus better to just change your tests, and check if it returns a 302.

Comment: so i should check to 302 for every post request which has redirection ?

Comment: @StackUser: yes.